# Teamcity Setup Issues

Tags: mysql, teamcity

Good day

I am trying to setup my first TeamCity instance. I'm running windows 2016 server with mysql. I'm busy setting up the database connection and i'm getting the error.

```
The MySQL JDBC driver is not found in the C:\ProgramData\JetBrains\TeamCity\lib\jdbc directory. 

Copy the driver .jar file to the directory. You can download it at http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j. 

For the MySQL server version 5.5 or higher, use the JDBC driver version 5.1.23 or higher.
```

But if i go to that link it doesn't give me the option to download a version for windows, it just has unix OS versions. Any help would be appreciated. ive been googling the issue but cant seem to find an answer for windows

Answer (score 0):

From the drop down list choose "Platform Independent".